# Базовые расширения Joomla (компоненты, модули)

Tags: joomla, php

Добрый день,

Как вы считаете, каков необходимый набор расширений для Joomla, для создания простенького сайта.

Что-то типа 10-20 лучших расширений для joomla :)

К примеру joomfish для создания многоязычного ресурса..

Спасибо.

Comment: После нескольких лет работы с джумлой могу сказать так: стандартные + com_php + mod_php + массив `$_ENV`. Юзать то, что делает школоло(95% бесплатных компонентов/модулей), с тупейшими багами и кодом либо нечитаемым, либо php3-style - очень быстро кончаются нервы и заплетаются пальцы.

Comment: Извините за оффтоп, но выбросьте Joomla и держитесь от нее подальше, мой вам совет, что бы нервы были здоровые и т.д ...

Comment: И что использовать вместо Joomla?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все зависит от того в каком направлении хотите делать сайт ))) Либо это интернет-магазин, либо блог, либо новостной портал, либо портфолио и т.д.
Для всего этого существует множество расширений, которое насчитывате аж до 5000 штук. Но не стоит ими переусердствовать, чтобы не сделать сайт скучным и не интересным

Comment: интересна была бы информация типо:
 - для блога я обычно ставлю этот, этот, этот плагин и остальное подпиливаю для каждого клиент отдельно..
 - для интернет магазина, обычно сначала устанавливается это, это, это..  
и т.д. в том же духе.. Т.е. Нужен ответ опытного человека, создавшего не один проект на жумле..

Answer (score 1):

Ставьте те модули, которые нужны. Если магазин - ставьте VirtueMart, например. Нет ведь одинаковых задач, у всех всё разное.

Answer (score 1):

Отвечая за себя, я обычно ставлю Linkr, для создания внутренних ссылок в материалах и Phoca Gallery, если нужна галерея. Ну и менюшки, но тут на любителя.

Comment: Хороший ответ.. но не полный.. Почитайте мой коммент к ответу @Metrologik